# Relation between mereology and relevant logic?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, relevant-logic

I’ve seen work before on relevance logic and set theory, but is there some connection too between relevance logic and mereology? I’ve heard that mereological relations are akin to the inclusion relation in set theory. Could there be a “relevant mereology”?

Comment: There has been work in developing mereological theories using a paraconsistent underlying logic. Googling "paraconsistent mereology" throws up some references.